# Android : load next objects in ArrayAdapter by clicking on Item "load next Objects"

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have an `ArrayAdapter<Cars>` which shows my `Cars` in a List. That is good, but i want it to load other `Cars` dynamically by clicking on the last item in the list.
 
The last item should not be a `Cars` element it should only be a item which contains a `TextView` with text, for example *"Load Next Items"*. Example: I have 13 `Cars` then the list would look like: *Car/Car/Car/"Load Next Item"*.
When I click on that last item the next 3 `Cars` would be shown AND the *"Load Next Item"* and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are not actually using `ListView` here.

you can bind an onclick listener function to `Load next item`.

That function will get the current set_of_cars_displayed (initially 0) and get set of cars as `set_of_cars_displayed * 3` to `(set_of_cars_displayed +1) * 3`. This should be basic idea, you can post difficulty you are facing in implementation if any...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this with just an ArrayAdapter since everything has to be the same type.
What I would do is create my own class that extends BaseAdapter.
That class would have your array of cars and based in the getView method you can check the position and if it's the last one that your currently wanting to display you'll be able to inflate a different for the "click next" and assign and an click listener that will update your Array of cars . So you'll probably have to add a +1 to your getcount method for this last item. Don't forget to call notifydatasetchanged() to redraw your new elements.